# magento show product detail page for logged only

Tags: product

i want to show product detail page to logged in user only how can i do this ?? user will be redirected to login page if he is not logged.

I guess if any way so that i can do it via created a custome .phml file and called it to header of product info (custom deign of category section )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an observer for the event `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view` that looks like this:

For this you need an extension.
Let's call it `Easylife_Restriction`.
Is should contain the following files:

`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Restriction.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Restriction>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Restriction>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Restriction/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Restriction>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Restriction>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
             <easylife_restriction>
                 <class>Easylife_Restriction_Model</class>
             </easylife_restriction>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
             <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
                 <observers>
                      <easylife_restriction>
                           <class>easylife_restriction/observer</class>
                           <method>redirectToLogin</method>
                      </easylife_restriction>
                 </observers>
             </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Restriction/Model/Observer.php` - the actual observer

```
class Easylife_Restriction_Model_Observer {
    public function redirectToLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        }
    }
}
```

Clear the cache when you are done.
[Read here more about how event-observers work in Magento.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: where can i put that file and call it

Comment: @saurav. See my update answer. I just created an extension for you

Comment: Good works @Marius..upvote from me:)