# magento show products and catagories page for logged users only

Tags: magento-1.9

[magento show product detail page for logged only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37892/magento-show-product-detail-page-for-logged-only/67643#67643)

In this topic its showed that how to show products view page to logged users only.

But i don't want to show all products and categories page to visitors.
i want to show only to logged in users.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add another event `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view`  which fire on category page dispatch time.

```
 <events>
             <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view>
                 <observers>
                      <easylife_restriction_category>
                           <class>easylife_restriction/observer</class>
                           <method>redirectToLogin</method>
                      </easylife_restriction_category>
                 </observers>
             </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view>
        </events>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit u are my hero. i want to give you a vote. how can i ? i don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: its working perfect.